# Magento 1 : duplicate data in description and short description

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attributes, frontend, products

Magento 1.9 based website.

i am facing a wierd issue while updating short description and description via import or manually, that data is getting duplicated i.e. when i try to update description and short description the product page shows same data as description on short description.

example : if i write 'printed skater dress' at description and 'skaters for girls' at short description and save it but on frontend it shows 'printed skater dress' at both description and short description places.

request if anyone can guide.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check following way..

1. Try to clear cache.
2. Indexing.
3. Check code for displaying product attribute.

To display product description & short description ....

```
$product->getShortDescription() -- Short description
$product->getDescription()      -- Description
```